# Localhost does not send email in php

Tags: php, email, xampp

I'm trying to send an email with my php script which already works in live server but I also want to be able to send email from my localhost. Basically I'm using Xampp and on `php.ini` I searched for `sendmail_path` and then  make it out of comment by removing the **;** and it is set to `sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i"`.

But I don't know why it does not work !!

So do you know what's going wrong ?! If you do please let me know ,I really appreciate that.. thanks.

Comment: To send a mail  you need a mail server to be installed with a static ip provided by your ISP without that it won't send mail  for security reason .. As if localhost could send the mail then no one will be able to trace the email. Except if you are using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some diagnostic in such scenario.

1. Check if sendmail client is properly installed and configured
2. If sendmail is installed and configured then check the username and password that you are supplying.